# Learning Classes C++ - Can't set values in an array of classes nested within another class.

Tags: c++, class

I am super-new to classes and still wrapping my brain around how they work. Any help/advice/pointers-> are appreciated!

I have two classes. Within the second class is an array of the first class. I am trying to assign values to the private member variables contained in the array of the first class.

I get this error message when compiling:

```
hw2Test.cpp: In member function 'void bar::set(int)':
hw2Test.cpp:11:7: error: 'int foo::x' is private
   int x;
       ^
hw2Test.cpp:34:12: error: within this context
  foodoo[0].x = x;
            ^
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class foo
{
    public:


    private:
        int x;
};

class bar
{
    public:
        void set(int x);

    private:
        foo foodoo[1];
};

int main()
{
    bar tar;

    tar.set(1);

    return 0;
}

void bar::set(int x)
{
    foodoo[0].x = x;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo::x` is declared as `private`, so only methods of `foo` can access it.  But you are trying to access `x` inside of a method of `bar` instead, which does not have access to `foo`'s private members.

To give `bar` access, you need to either:

1. declare `foo::x` as `public`:

   ```
   class foo
   {
       public:
           int x;
   };

   void bar::set(int x)
   {
       foodoo[0].x = x;
   }
   ```
2. declare a `public` setter:

   ```
   class foo
   {
       public:
           void set(int i);

       private:
           int x;
   };

   void foo::set(int i)
   {
       foodoo[0].x = i;
   }

   void bar::set(int x)
   {
       foodoo[0].set(x);
   }
   ```
3. declare `bar` as a `friend` of `foo`:

   ```
   class foo
   {
       public:

       private:
           int x;

       friend class bar;
   };

   void bar::set(int x)
   {
       foodoo[0].x = x;
   }
   ```

Comment: There is a third option, provide accessor methods.

Comment: By provide accessor methods, do you mean calling a fx inside of bar that calls a fx inside of foo so I can get to foo's naughty bits?

Comment: @BuckWheat yes, exactly